# Задача двадцатигранника в игре Dungeons & Dragons

Tags: javascript

После вызова функции - функция показывает результат: число от 1 до 20.
В случае если результат 20 или 1, должно быть показано дополнительное число.

Результат:
dice()
3
dice()
1 14

Думал выполнить задачу, с помощью массива, где будет выбираться рандомное число, но не понимаю какой код выведет не 1, а 2 значение, если результат 1 или 20

```
let sizeOfDice =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] 

function getRandNumber(sizeOfDice) {
  
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * sizeOfDice.length); 
  
  return sizeOfDice[rand]
} 

getRandNumber(sizeOfDice)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Пытается получить готовый код ничего не делая

Comment: @HTOHOT Не известно автор что-то делал или нет, он мог пытаться, но не поделиться с нами кодом

Comment: Можно пожалуйста условие задачи в вопрос добавить? Или задача в выдаче рандомного числа от 1 до 20?

Comment: "дополнительное число" - это что за число? Тоже рандомное число от 1 до 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то что - то такое должно помочь. Если нужен вывод, то давайте добавим console.log, но если что можно и поменять. а второе условие с возвратом просто уберём. Функцию можно расширить, добавив входимый параметр в виде массива, чтобы при рекурсии у неё уже были предыдущие значения, после чего можно было вернуть их все сразу, чтобы работать с этими значениями дальше.

```
    function throwDice() {
      let dice;
      let min = 1,
          max = 20;

      dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      console.log(dice);
      if (dice === 20 || dice === 1) {
        throwDice();
      }
}
```

Если нужна работа с несколькими значениями - можно попробовать так. Он вам и выведет всё, что есть, и вернёт массив.

```
    function throwDice(results = []) {
      results = [];
      let dice;
      let min = 1,
          max = 20;

      dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      results.push(dice);
      console.log(dice);
      if (dice === 20 || dice === 1) {
        throwDice(results);
      } else {
        return results;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Немного неправильно поняли вы. Надо не просто второй раз подкинуть, а вернуть и предыдущее значение и результат второго броска

Answer (score 2):

Эту задачу можно решить и без массива

Математика:

- `Math.random()` - выдаёт занчения от 0 включительно до 1 не включительно. Далее включительно буду обозначать квадратными скобками, а не включительно круглыми. Т.е. `Math.random()` выдаёт значения `[0, 1)`
- Умножаем на 20 и получаем `[0, 20)`
- Округляя вверх получаем целое число из отрезка `[1, 20]`

```js
const dice = () => {
  const getRandomNumber = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
  
  const value1 = getRandomNumber();
  
  if (value1 === 1 || value1 === 20) {
    return [value1, getRandomNumber()]
  }
  
  return value1;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
  console.log(dice());
}
```

В приведённом выше примере, как указали в комментариях, есть очень маленькая вероятность получить 0. Дело в том, что если вдруг `Math.random()` выдаст ровно 0, то мой алгоритм вернёт просто 0. Чтобы этого избежать, можно функцию получения рандомного числа чутка подправить

Математика:

- `Math.random()` выдаёт значения `[0, 1)`
- Умножаем на 20 и получаем `[0, 20)`
- Округляя вниз и получаем `[0, 19]`
- Прибавляем 1 и получаем целое число из отрезка `[1, 20]`

```js
const dice = () => {
  const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
  
  const value1 = getRandomNumber();
  
  if (value1 === 1 || value1 === 20) {
    return [value1, getRandomNumber()]
  }
  
  return value1;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
  console.log(dice());
}
```

Comment: Есть крохотная вероятность получить ноль.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Всегда забивал на это, если честно, т.к. за 5 лет знакомства с JS ни разу не получал 0)) Но замечание справедливое, добавлю ещё вариант

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Добавил вариант, где точно будет минимум 1)

Comment: Добавлять `min` надо вне `Math.floor`, иначе есть возможность вылезти из диапазона вверх. Сравните: `Math.floor(20 + 20 * (1 - 0.5 ** 53)) == 40` - неправильно, `20 + Math.floor(20 * (1 - 0.5 ** 53)) == 39` - правильно. Извините за назойливость. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А, это из-за представления чисел я так понимаю, а не из-за математики самой. Тогда да, надо писать как вы сказали. Даже не думайте за такое извиняться, такие поправки - очень полезны)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Исправил, теперь стало лучше :)